# Proof concerning indexed family of sets

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Let $f: A \rightarrow B$ be a function. Let $I$ be a non-empty set, and let $\left\{U_i\right\}_{i \in I}$ be a family of sets indexed by $I$ such that $U_i \subset A$ for all $ i \in I$.

**Proof the following:** \begin{align*} f\left(\bigcap_{i \in I} U_i\right) \subset \bigcap_{i \in I} f(U_i). \end{align*}

**Proof:** Let $x \in f\left(\bigcap_{i \in I} U_i\right)$. Hence $x = f(u)$ for a certain $u \in \bigcap_{i \in I} U_i$. Then $u \in U_j$ for some $j \in I$, and so $x \in f(U_j)$ for some $j \in I$. Since $\bigcap_{i \in I} f(U_i) \subset f(U_j)$, we have that $x \in \bigcap_{i \in I} f(U_i)$. Hence it follows that $f\left(\bigcap_{i \in I} U_i\right) \subset \bigcap_{i \in I} f(U_i)$.

Is this proof correct or did I go wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake in the definition of $\bigcap$.

Recall that $a\in\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i$ if and only if $x\in A_i$ ***for all*** $i\in I$. Not for *some* $i\in I$.

So $u\in U_i$ for all $i\in I$, so $f(u)\in f(U_i)$ for all $i\in I$. This makes the last sentence a bit awkward as well, we can directly conclude that $\subseteq$ holds here.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So I have now: $u \in U_j$ for all $j \in I$, and so $x \in f(U_j)$ for all $j \in I$. Because we always have that $\bigcap_{i \in I} f(U_i) \subset f(U_j)$, the conclusion then follows?

Comment: Well, you can replace it by since $x\in f(U_j)$ for all $j\in I$ it follows that $x\in\bigcap_{j\in I} f(U_j)$. And that is what you had to show, that given $x$ on the LHS, it is an element of the RHS.